# Как заблокировать изменения AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio при сборке переписывает манифест который написан в проекте.
Что конкретно делает:
 вместо строки

```
<activity android:name="WinActivity">
```

в собранном приложении в манифесте будет

```
<activity android:name="Com.my.package.WinActivity">
```

Есть ли возможность или полностью заблокировать изменение манифеста или эту подмену как-то убрать.

Зачем это надо - проблема в Capital letter и имени пакета. Заглавной буквы. Приложение было давно собрано на Eclipse и там все работало нормально, была публикация в гугл плей и там есть пользователи. Соответственно имя пакета поменять нельзя (так как гуглплей не разрешит обновить приложение)
А при той сборке что делает Android студия в итоге, на устройствах получается ошибка error parsing package.
Я решил проблему с помощью apktools распаковал, поправил манифест и запаковал обнатно, но блин.. может просто можно сказать Android Studio чтоб не вносила правки в манифест ?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `tools:replace="android:name"` в тег активии

Comment: Если имя активности прописано без пакета, то будет подставлен пакет приложения, что в студии, что в эклипсе. Пропишите имя полностью - с пакетом, в котором у Вас реально лежит активность. Имя пакета, в котором лежит класс `Activity` менять можно - оно не обязано совпадать с `applicationId`.

Comment: Нет, как в в Eclipse он не проставлял пути в манифест я прям сегодня декомпилировал старый проект и посмотрел в его манифест, в итоге помогло реально перенести все классы просто в другой пакет и прописать к нему везде пути явно, а пакет по дефолту пустой в котором нет ни одного класса - так заработало все.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в gradle скрипте выставить application-id https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#change_the.package_name

Как-то так:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "Com.my.package"
```

Comment: нет, не сработало.